# Is it equivalent to put something as part of the path and as a parameter?

Tags: google-app-engine, url, webapp2

Right now I have two ways of accomplishing (apparently) the same thing in my application. I can either make my urls look like this https://something/product/shirt or https://something/product?q=shirt. In both cases I can extract what I need from it, which is shirt.

First way (with a regular expression):

```py
class FirstHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, page_id):
        target = page_id

PAGE_RE = r'(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)'
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/something' + PAGE_RE, FirstHandler)],
                               debug=True)
```

The second way in which I can deal with it is using a parameter, which would look like this:

```py
class SecondHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        target = self.request.get('q')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/something' SecondHandler)],
                               debug=True)
```

My question is, are these methods equivalent? Is it the same if I do one or the other or do I have to take something else into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at all of the requests that you expect to make, and decide which of them should be represented by unique endpoints (`/shirt`), and which will allow one or more parameters. You can combine these approaches when necessary.

There is no performance penalty or any other advantage of using url path or parameters. The key factors are:

- how easy it is to understand your API if it is or will be used by outside developers
- how easy it is to organize and maintain your code
- how flexible is your approach when you need to expand it

For example, `/shirt` may look like a good idea now, but once you have thousands of product types, it becomes a nightmare to maintain. Instead, you may want to use something like:

```
/product/?type=shirt&size=10&orderBy=price&results=20&offset=40
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.yaml` can pre-route for you (to different WSGI app -- even, with `dispatch.yaml`'s help, to different *modules*), based on URLs, but *not* based on specific queries to a given URL.

So, if you identify the resource as `/something/product/shirt`, you *may* in the future "administratively" (by altering `app.yaml` and maybe `dispatch.yaml` configuration files, not Python code) pre-route certain products to different WSGI apps or even modules; if you identify it as `/something/product?q=shirt`, the administrative, config-file based routing will be to a single WSGI app based on `/something/product` only, and then it will be up to the code serving that app to deal w/the query part.

So, other things equal, you may prefer to use URLs to keep more routing flexibility for the future. Query-parts are precious for such things as optional parameters and order independence -- imagine e.g `/something/product/shirt?fmt=json&size=xl`, where `fmt` and `size` are both optional with some default and may optionally occur in any order, that would be nasty/complex to do with URLs only while it's trivially easy  to achieve with queries.

But a "query syntax" with a single *mandatory* parameter is a (moderate) "API design smell" -- and not just in App Engine, either; while App Engine has its own routing and dispatching mechanisms, they're not particularly out of line with what you could expect from other servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the moment the application is small and will not get much traffic, so I was interested in performance (which now I understand is not affected by the decision). I will take what you said into account for future projects.